# Read/Delete email from all mailboxes Outlook365

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

How can I access emails from all mailboxes within a domain using the Graph API?

I am currently trying, using the Graph Explorer, to get the properties from a certain email in a mailbox within my domain. The office account I am logged in on is an Admin account within this domain.

For example:

my user is `admin_user@foo-bar.com` and has the following permissions in Graph `Mail.ReadWrite`.

I can successfully use the following query:

```
/v1.0/users/admin_user@foo-bar.com/messages?$filter=internetMessageId eq '{id}'
```

But when i try:

```
/v1.0/users/other_user@foo-bar.com/messages?$filter=internetMessageId eq '{id}'
```

It returns a `403` exception.

Is there a problem with the permissions set or does the `admin_user` not have enough rights over the mailbox for `other_user`?

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, `Mail.ReadWrite` only provides access to the current user's mailbox. This is true even if they are an Admin.

The only way to get around this would be to use App-only (aka `client_credentials`). This would allow your app to read/write any mailbox on the system. See [Get access without a user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service).